# Displaying the values of a function call in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Let's say I have this line of code in a .c file:

```
 function(int a, int b);
```

If I set a breakpoint at this function in gdb, how can I print out the values of a and b? It seems like a simple question but I have not found anything online about this.

Comment: `print a` `print b` as for all variables, just rtfm. But the actual values are already shown when the breakpoint is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print <variable name>` or `p <variable-name>`